# MooTools: Set focus on click

Tags: asp.net, javascript, mootools

I've got an ASP.NET control that contains a checkbox. I want the focus to remain on this checkbox when it's clicked. Here's what I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent("domready", function() {

        var acceptCheckId = $("<%= this.accept.ClientID %>").getElement("input");

        acceptCheckId.addEvent("click", function() {
            acceptCheckId.focus();
        });

    });
</script>
```

I can get the checkbox element into the `acceptCheckId` variable okay, but when I click on it, the focus doesn't change. What gives?

If I add an alert in, the alert never fires:

```
    acceptCheckId.addEvent("click", function() {
        alert("foobar");
        acceptCheckId.focus();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your output HTML look like?  it's impossible to say what's wrong w/ the code w/o knowing how your <% %> content is written.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent("domready", function() {

    var acceptCheckId = $("<%= this.accept.ClientID %>").getElement("input"); 
    // $('elementId').getChildren('input');
    // You can't put an entire element in there                                                 

    acceptCheckId.addEvent("click", function() {
        acceptCheckId.focus();
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){
  acceptCheckId.focus(); // this may execute ok 
},200);
```

When you click an element, the element will get focus, and you can't focus other element now, because this element will get focus first, and use `setTimeout`, may delay sometime, and after this time, you can set focus to any element.

look the click execution order: 
click  --> execute onclick function --> get focus -->

In step 2, the onclick function, you set focus to other element, but, after execution the onclick function, the element itself should get focus, this done by web browser!